# Non SMTP email with Python

Tags: python

I want to send emails with custom 'FROM' field, like *noreply@example_company.com*, it's easy to do in PHP, but I don't know how to do that in python and can't find any good documentation.

in other words, what is the python equivalent of the following php code?

```
$to = "user@gmail.com";
$subject = "Weekly news";
$message = "Hello, you've got new Like";
$from = "noreply@example_company.com";
$headers = "From: WeekNews" . '<'.$from.'>';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Note that there is no need to setup SMTP server connection, you just give it a custom $from address.

Comment: I didn't know that. Then how do I send one from my localhost, instead of using some email service like gmail?

Comment: SMTP is what sends the email, its just that some times it doesn't reflect in the code because defaults are assumed or config files are referred.

Answer (score 2):

You will always have to send it to some smtp server, this is in fact what php also does, it uses the settings from php.ini on windows and the local mail delivery system on unix.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

from the python documentation:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/email-examples.html

```
mailFrom = 'from.user@somedomain.com'
mailTo = ['to.user1@somedomain.com', 'to.user2@somedomain.com']
subject = 'mail subject'
message = 'the message body'

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = mailFrom
msg['To'] = ", ".join(mailTo)
# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(message, 'text')
part2 = MIMEText(message, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
failed_addr = s.sendmail(mailFrom, mailTo, msg.as_string())
print("failed addresses: {f}".format(f = failed_addr))
s.quit()
```